# Segmentation fault Core dumped parallel arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I'm quite new to C++ I'm just trying to read a text file that has a string and two decimal numbers in each line. I get a segmentation fault when I try to read them into the arrays....I'm still learning about arrays and can't figure out why this won't work for the life of me. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;
string fileLocation;
ifstream newList;


string city[ARRAY_SIZE];
double lowTemp[ARRAY_SIZE];
double highTemp[ARRAY_SIZE];

int LoadData (char com);
void ShowAll (int count);

int main()
{
    char command;
    cout << "Welcome to David's Libary Database!" << endl << endl << "(L)oad File, (S)how All, (F)ind City, (Q)uit ";
    cin >> command;
    LoadData(command);
    return 0;
}
int LoadData(char com)
{
    int index = 0;
    double tempLow, tempHi;
    string singleCity;
    if(com == 'l' || com == '1' || com == 'L')
    {
        cout << "Please provide a file path: ";
        cin >> fileLocation;
        newList.open(fileLocation.c_str());
        if(!newList.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Please provide a file path: ";
            cin >> fileLocation;
            newList.open(fileLocation.c_str());
            if(!newList.is_open())
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        while(!newList.eof())
        {
            newList >> singleCity >> tempLow >> tempHi;
            city[index] = singleCity;
            lowTemp[index] = tempLow;
            highTemp[index] = tempHi;
            index++;
       }
        cout << index +1 << " record(s) found." << endl;
        cout << city[0];
        newList.close();
        newList.clear(std::ios_base::goodbit);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're expecting `eof` to predict whether or not a future read will encounter the end of the file. It can't possibly know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No obvious reason for a seg fault unless you happen to have more than 1000 entries in your file.

I'm going to take a guess and say that the reason for your error is that your reading loop is incorrect. Allway test if your reads succeed. If a read failed but not because of end of file then your loop would go for ever. I think that might be what is happening in this case. In any case `newfile.eof()` does not do what you obviously think it does, it does **not** test if you are at the end of file.

Here's the right way to write your loop, try this and see if it makes any difference

```
while (newList >> singleCity >> tempLow >> tempHi)
{
    city[index] = singleCity;
    lowTemp[index] = tempLow;
    highTemp[index] = tempHi;
    index++;
}
```

See how this code actually tests if the read succeeds (by putting the read itself in the while condition).

Another error

```
cout << index +1 << " record(s) found." << endl;
```

is one too many, should be

```
cout << index << " record(s) found." << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, so how would I deal with the same situation if it was a comma delimited file?

Comment: @Napalm6b Depends on exactly what you've got. But I would expect you to read one lines at a time using std::getline to give you a string, and then to *tokenize* the string, which essentially means spliting it at the commas, and then converting each field as necessary. There's nothing built in to C++ to do this for you. You have to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `while(!newList.eof())` to check end of file.
You should modify it as,

```
while(newList >> singleCity >> tempLow >> tempHi)
{
    city[index] = singleCity;
    lowTemp[index] = tempLow;
    highTemp[index] = tempHi;
    index++;
}
```

This is provided that the city doesn't have any whitespace between the characters. Your input file should be,

```
NY 23 24
LA 13 18
```

It will fail if your input file as,

```
New York 23 24
Los Angeles 13 18
```

And you should check whether it is out of bound of the `city[]` array.

Comment: Why not put all the operator>> into the while condition?

Comment: @john: is there any benefit from putting all the operators>> into the loop? Readable code?

Comment: It tests if all the variables are read successfully. In the case of 'New York' then `newList >> singleCity` will succeed, so the loop continues, but `newList >> tempLow` will fail (because York isn't a number) so you get bad data into your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , try compile with `g++ -g`, and run `gdb` to get the stacktrace so that you know where the segment fault occurs.

In your code:

```
    while(!newList.eof())
    {
        newList >> singleCity >> tempLow >> tempHi;
        city[index] = singleCity;
        lowTemp[index] = tempLow;
        highTemp[index] = tempHi;
        index++;
   }
```

If the index becomes larger than ARRAY_SIZE, you get segmentation fault.